# How to understand the geometry of bilinear forms that are not positive-definite?

Tags: reference-request, vector-spaces, intuition, bilinear-form

I simply cannot find a good resource that explains intuitively how to understand the geometry that is induced on a vector space when the bilinear form is not positive-definite. In the ordinary Euclidean case, we have nice formulas that give us the length of vectors and the angle between them, but apparently these notions break down in the absence of positive-definiteness. How should I try to visualize these strange geometries? What sort of picture should I keep in my mind when I try to imagine, for instance, a symplectic form? Any thorough explanation or reference to an adequate resource would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Matt Samuel Well then, what sorts of things arise from the forms? What do the forms tell us about the vectors?

Comment: That is a reasonable question. I don't have a good answer for you, but hopefully someone will come along who does.

Comment: @MattSamuel I'm no expert but I guess that physicists would claim that Lorentz geometry provides a geometric picture of relativistic spacetime, by means of a dot product that is not positive definite.

Comment: @MiguelAtencia True. And it seems that an arbitrary nondegenerate metric tensor on a manifold is considered a pseudometric. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold 
Maybe the citations will be helpful.

Comment: @MattSamuel True, but that is precisely one part of the motivation of the question - that I might be able to gain some headway on understanding Lorentzian geometry.

Comment: @MattSamuel No, I do not. Do you recommend I get one? It's not really part of my studies, just an area of personal interest. I'm really more interested in the general question, and was hoping that an increased understanding of special relativity might come out from it like a convenient domino.

Comment: If you're more interested in the general question, by all means stick with it. Maybe studying particular cases will help (likely even), but you may have noticed that the geometric aspect is not my area of expertise so I can't give you an informed recommendation.

Comment: I don't think you can get much of an inuitive understanding, as there are numerous aspects that violate our experienced-based intuition. It is only by slogging through it that we can develop new experiences that develop a new intuition appropriate to a space where certain directions have no length. At each point, you can consider the space as a product of two well-behaved Reimannian spaces. And as long as you stick to moving around in one or the other, everything is normal. But when you try to move through both at the same time. Intuition gives us no hints.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Could you recommend a good resource where I might be able to develop such an intuition? Forge it through exercises.

Comment: Alas, I can't. I haven't been actively involved in the field in years, and the references I have don't strike me as particularly good for this. I have "Semi-Riemannian Geometry" by Barrett O'Niell in front of me, which has some good insights in it, but it takes a while before he gets to the more intuitive parts of the matter, and I will not guarantee he does any better than the references you already have.